# Create a Sub sheet from Master Sheet, using import range, filter and match Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, match

I want to fetch data from a google sheet data dump/master sheet. There is a sheet for each month. Import/match the data to columns that are in a different order in another sub spreadsheet and put all months on one sheet. Lastly, I want to filter the data by person, status and date, so only these items will show unless Cell H1 is populated. If cell H1 is populated and not null, all data that meets the criteria will  be shown.

Master: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nIzCqQUL1K4HwYUGV0jxjJjLKSFaeqVn27f_pkoL9j0/edit?usp=sharing

Subsheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-V0F_pJTKFmP8jRBwpIzBe_sP7GbC-314oUB97N0K-0/edit#gid=0

```
function Importmatchfilter() {

  // source sheet
var ss = ('1nIzCqQUL1K4HwYUGV0jxjJjLKSFaeqVn27f_pkoL9j0/edit#gid=1395833187');
  var ssn1 = ss.getSheetByName('April'); ('A:Z')
 var ssn2 = ss.getSheetByName('May'); ('A:Z')
   var ssn3 = ss.getSheetByName('June'); ('A:Z')
  var ssn4 = ss.getSheetByName('July'); ('A:Z')
  var ssn5 = ss.getSheetByName('August'); ('A:Z')
  var ssn6 = ss.getSheetByName('September'); ('A:Z')
  var ssn7 = ss.getSheetByName('October'); ('A:Z')
  var ssn8 = ss.getSheetByName('November'); ('A:Z')
  var ssn9 = ss.getSheetByName('December'); ('A:Z')

  // Get full range of data
  var SRange1 = ssn1.getDataRange();
    var SRange2 = ssn2.getDataRange();
    var SRange3 = ssn3.getDataRange();
    var SRange4 = ssn4.getDataRange();
    var SRange5 = ssn5.getDataRange();
    var SRange6 = ssn6.getDataRange();
    var SRange7 = ssn7.getDataRange();
    var SRange8 = ssn8.getDataRange();
  var SRange9 = ssn9.getDataRange();

  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange1.getA1Notation();
    var A1Range1 = SRange1.getA1Notation();
    var A1Range2 = SRange2.getA1Notation();
    var A1Range3 = SRange3.getA1Notation();
    var A1Range4 = SRange4.getA1Notation();
    var A1Range5 = SRange5.getA1Notation();
    var A1Range6 = SRange6.getA1Notation();
    var A1Range7 = SRange7.getA1Notation();
    var A1Range8 = SRange8.getA1Notation();
    var A1Range9 = SRange9.getA1Notation();


  // get the data values in range
  var SData1 = SRange1.getValues();
  var SData2 = SRange2.getValues();
  var SData3 = SRange3.getValues();
  var SData4 = SRange4.getValues();
  var SData5 = SRange5.getValues();
  var SData6 = SRange6.getValues();
  var SData7 = SRange7.getValues();
  var SData8 = SRange8.getValues();
   var SData9 = SRange9.getValues();


  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  function listMajors() {
        gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
          spreadsheetId: '1-V0F_pJTKFmP8jRBwpIzBe_sP7GbC-314oUB97N0K-0',
          range: A1
        }).then(function(response) {
          var range = response.result;
          if (range.values.length > 0) {
            appendPre('Due date, Status, Address:');
            for (i = 0; i < range.values.length; i++) {
              var row = range.values[i];

              appendPre(row[0] + ', ' + row[4]);

              function getheaderValues(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
                var range = sheet.getRange("A:Z");
  var allOfColumnAz = range.getValues()

  for (var i = 1; i < 10 ; i++){ 
    var sData = eval("SData"+i); 
    var lastRow = ts.getLastRow(); 
    var numRows = sData.length; 
    var numCols = sData[0].length; 
    ts.getRange(lastRow+(lastRow > 0 ? 2 : 1), 1, numRows, numCols).setValues(sData);
  }}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to accomplish. The code you provided is quite messed up and is using the API, which I'm not sure you want to use. Please try making your explanation clearer. Are you aware that `Status` doesn't exist in the origin spreadsheet? Which fields should be in the origin and the destination spreadsheet? And how should the filter work? What criteria should data meet in order to be shown? Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Basically, what we are trying to do is a master sheet that populates a sub sheet. We would like the data to be looped so if you update one sheet they both update. The sheet is in a different order than the master sheet and not all data needs to be fetched.The data on the sub sheet is filtered by person/department so they can only see they’re open items. The example sheets may vary from code because they were created as an example off the real data. Thank you again!